# Postgres - basic security settings

Tags: postgresql, security, configuration

I'm setting up a PostgreSQL instance for some logging data (non-critical). It will be accessible from internet. It's hosted on an azure VM.

I'm wondering what would be a decent setup to have basic security.

So far I come up with this:

- change default port to 51234
- turn on ssl
- allow superuser login only from localhost
- dedicated NOSUPERUSER for connections from internet

Any other tips?

Comment: https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/postgresql

Comment: Changing the port is just "security through obscurity" and is not best practice. You should always act as if your exposed ports are published in large font in every newspaper in the world!

Comment: but it works, right ? :-)

Comment: What is your threat model?  That someone will steal your non-critical data and sell it?  Steal your processing power to mine cryptocurrencies?  Trick your users into logging onto a fake server, where they can steal their passwords?  Their query texts?

Comment: The 3rd on the list is by far the most important.  After that is probably, pick passwords that don't suck and are never used elsewhere.

Comment: @user49126 `but it works, right ?` - no, it doesn't work. That's why it's **not** considered best practice!